# First Run Is Not Compiling Due To Missing Texture Errors

Tags: android-layout, android-studio

Thank you for your time. Whenever I try to run the program I recieve this error message

```
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored'.



Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Colored'.
```

Photo of error: [http://imgur.com/a/P4ooW](https://imgur.com/a/P4ooW)

Photo of project structure: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CljBH.jpg

Please help me in my problem to fix this program. I am a novice programmer and learning everything on my own. Much thanks.